# How do I load that bar graph from Excel to Matlab and plot it in Matlab

Tags: matlab

hi   i want  to upload   a excel sheet  to matlab and after that  wanted to plot  a 3D graph  based on that  sheet

Comment: Where is the data located in the excel file? You should take a look at the `xlsread` function in matlab

Answer (score 0):

using the xlsread function in matlab you can read the excel files.  For a more indepth look visit this link http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to import the data interactively, you should use the import tool.  Once you have done it interactively once, you can generate code which will automate the process.

Here is a tutorial: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/new-spreadsheet-import-tool-in-r2011b-69037.html

[image]